# Converting SOAP request to XML format

Tags: xml, soap

I'm wondering on how to change a request into XML format. I am working on a project with other XML requests and cannot find an alternative that works in converting this SOAP request, any thoughts?

The documentation I have is very old and only shows these requests in SOAP format.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v16="http://fedex.com/ws/track/v16">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <v16:TrackRequest>
      <v16:WebAuthenticationDetail>
        <v16:ParentCredential>
          <v16:Key>INPUT YOUR INFORMATION</v16:Key>
          <v16:Password>INPUT YOUR INFORMATION</v16:Password>
        </v16:ParentCredential>
        <v16:UserCredential>
          <v16:Key>INPUT YOUR INFORMATION</v16:Key>
          <v16:Password>INPUT YOUR INFORMATION</v16:Password>
        </v16:UserCredential>
      </v16:WebAuthenticationDetail>
      <v16:ClientDetail>
        <v16:AccountNumber>XXXXXXXXX</v16:AccountNumber>
        <v16:MeterNumber>XXXXXXX</v16:MeterNumber>
      </v16:ClientDetail>
      <v16:TransactionDetail>
        <v16:CustomerTransactionId>Track By Number_v16</v16:CustomerTransactionId>
        <v16:Localization>
          <v16:LanguageCode>EN</v16:LanguageCode>
          <v16:LocaleCode>US</v16:LocaleCode>
        </v16:Localization>
      </v16:TransactionDetail>
      <v16:Version>
        <v16:ServiceId>trck</v16:ServiceId>
        <v16:Major>16</v16:Major>
        <v16:Intermediate>0</v16:Intermediate>
        <v16:Minor>0</v16:Minor>
      </v16:Version>
      <v16:SelectionDetails>
        <v16:CarrierCode>FDXE</v16:CarrierCode>
        <v16:PackageIdentifier>
          <v16:Type>TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG</v16:Type>
          <v16:Value>INPUT YOUR INFORMATION</v16:Value>
        </v16:PackageIdentifier>
        <v16:ShipmentAccountNumber/>
        <v16:SecureSpodAccount/>
        <v16:Destination>
          <v16:GeographicCoordinates>rates evertitque
aequora</v16:GeographicCoordinates>
        </v16:Destination>
      </v16:SelectionDetails>
    </v16:TrackRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: I have to confuse you, but SOAP **is** XML (with a specific namespace declaration). So your question is kind of strange.

Comment: Maybe you can be slightly more specific. Do you actually need to transform the message, or do you just need the XML without the SOAP elements that it is wrapped in?  As zx485 already mentioned, a SOAP message is XML

Comment: I guess it would be both, primarily I need the XML without the SOAP elements and dont know how to go about transforming that properly